# Trying to write greek words in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

What i want to do is  a part of a greek spelling programm. I won't get into much info about the classes etc. But i'm currectly working on a class that asks the user to input a greek text , but it can't understand greek letters and printing random stuff like "β•¬β–’β•§Ξ”β•¬β–’"  even tho i have changed the settings  to utf-8 in Window-Preferences-General-Workspace-Text file encoding set to utf-8 and from Project-Propertied-Resource-other(utf-8)

```
public static void main(String[]args) {



    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"cp737"));
        String str = "";


        str = in.readLine();
        // Create the encoder and decoder for ISO-8859-7
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("cp737");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();

        // Convert a string to ISO-LATIN-7 bytes in a ByteBuffer
        // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
        ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(str));

        // Convert ISO-LATIN-7 bytes in a ByteBuffer to a character ByteBuffer and then to a string
        // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
        CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
        String s = cbuf.toString();
        System.out.println(new String(s.getBytes(),"Cp1253"));


        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Comment: In the launch configuration set the encoding in the tab _Common_ to the same value as in your code.

Comment: Why are you using the cp737 character set to read in the first place? Changing the InputStreamReader to "UTF-8" will allow this program to read Greek inputs.